# Threaded runnable object method not responding to changes

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I have a class "HConnection" containing multiple methods such as abort(); and awaitConnection();

The awaitConnection(); method is called in my SWT Form main class using a runnable thread. Anyways, when i abort() the HConnection, the awaitConnection isn't aborted while it should be.

Have a look at this snapshot of my main code:

```
private HConnection connectie;

private void btnConnect_clicked(SelectionEvent e) {

    if (btnNewButton_1.getText().equals("Connect")) {
        String Url = combo.getText();
        connectie = new HConnection(Url);
        connectie.prepare();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                    connectie.awaitConnection();

                    Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            lblNewLabel_2.setText("Waiting -> client");
                            if (connectie.getState() == 2)  {
                                lblNewLabel_2.setText("Replacing URL");
                            }
                            else    {
                                lblNewLabel_2.setText("Failed");
                                connectie.abort();
                                btnNewButton_1.setText("Connect");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    if (connectie.getState() == 2)  {
                        // go on

                    }
              }
        }).start();

        ////////

        btnNewButton_1.setText("Abort");
    }
    else if(btnNewButton_1.getText().equals("Abort"))   {
        connectie.abort();
        lblNewLabel_2.setText("Aborted");
        btnNewButton_1.setText("Connect");
    }
```

And a snapshot of HConnection:

```
public void prepare()   {
    addToHostsFile("127.0.0.1" + "\t" + domain);
    state = 1;
}

public void abort() {
    removeFromHostsFile("127.0.0.1" + "\t" + domain);
    waitingConnection = false;
    HostFileEdited = false;
    state = 0;
}

public void awaitConnection()   {
    if (state == 1) {
        waitingConnection = true;
        System.out.println("0");
        while (/* not found && */ state == 1)   {

            // code

        }
        System.out.println("1");
        waitingConnection = false;
        if (state == 1) state = 2;
    }

}
```

One more note; the abort() function did actually work and finished the thread when I tried calling connectie.abort() directly after the thread.start();, (placed "////////" in the code above on that spot)
But if it's called where it should be called, it do what it should do 
while

```
lblNewLabel_2.setText("Aborted");
btnNewButton_1.setText("Connect");
```

are doing their job as expected

Comment: Maybe your else block inside run() method is not getting executed

Comment: @VikasSachdeva no thats not the problem

Comment: Sometimes threads do not start immediately, so when you invoke abort after you called `start` on your thread, the `awaitConnection()` might not even be invoked

Comment: @MerveSahin thanks for telling

Comment: Do you have any blocking code inside that `while`?

Comment: there is nothing inside the while loop yet, I'm building up in steps @Roman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your state and awaitConnection volatile :

```
private volatile int state;
private volatile boolean awaitConnection;
```

Comment: This did it! Thanks